# JBOSS 5.1.0: Undeploy of one module deleting the jars of another module

Tags: soap, jms, apache-axis, jboss5.x

There two independent wars files like War1 and War2. Both having axis2 web services. When we deploy a module into JBOSS EAP 5.1.0, Jboss explode the war file and creates unzipped file (exploded file) into tmp folder of jboss profile.

When we want to release a new version of the war, we un-deploy the old version and deploy the new version. While releasing a new version for WAR1 some of the jars from lib folder of another WAR2 are getting deleted and due to this other module of that war is not working properly. We are using soap over MQ for invoking web service. The issue is only occurring in the production environment.

Has anyone else come across any situation like this?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is due to old version of Jboss and I think its a bug of them. I will recommend you to try with newer Jboss.

We have been using Jboss-eap-6.2 and doing similar task but never face this type of problem.

Comment: I agree with you. It might be due to the older version. But we can't migrate to 6.2 as it involves migration of the all the application. We are unable to find out the root cause of the issue using Jboss 5.1.0.